# На чем написаны сложные GUI?

Tags: gui

Например, 3ds max, maya, photoshop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Все высокоуровневые библиотеки - либо удобная обёртка над WinAPI, либо они рисуют и обрабатывают все элементы управления вручную, например, через OpenGL или Direct3D. К первым относятся MFC, Windows Forms, GTK, и, по-моему, wxWidgets. Ко вторым - QT, WPF.

GUI можно рисовать и самому, используя OpenGL и Direct3D.

Если хочешь узнать, что использует какая-та опредделённая программа, поищи у неё в папке dll-библиотеки. Например, ты можешь найти там `MFC71.dll`. Это значит, что программа использует MFC. Если увидишь dll, содержащую в имени `Qt`, значит используется QT. Если программа использует чистый только WinAPI, OpenGL или Direct3D, то ты ничего такого не найдёшь.

Comment: Спасибо, кажется, посмотреть используемые dll можно через Dependency Walker.

Answer (score 0):

Photoshop раньше точно был написан с использованием Qt, коммерческой версии. Сейчас, может быть, тоже.

Comment: То то он так тормозил всегда :)